# React-Bootstrap Button resizes when Glyphicon is applied

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, react-bootstrap

For some reason my code causes the react-bootstrap Button to resize when the Glyphicon is applied when loading.

Here is my code:

**LoaderButton.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Glyphicon } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./LoaderButton.css";

export default ({
  isLoading,
  text,
  loadingText,
  className = "",
  disabled = false,
  ...props
}) => (
  <Button
    className={`LoaderButton ${className}`}
    disabled={disabled || isLoading}
    {...props}
  >
    {isLoading && <Glyphicon glyph="refresh" className="spinning" />}
    {!isLoading ? text : loadingText}
  </Button>
);
```

**LoaderButton.css**

```
.LoaderButton .spinning.glyphicon {
    margin-right: 7px;
    top: 2px;
    animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}
  @keyframes spin {
    from { transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Now this is where it gets odd...

**Search.js**

```
renderForm() {
    return (
      <div className="TableQuery">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <LoaderButton
            block
            bsSize="large"
            disabled={!this.validateForm()}
            type="submit"
            isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
            text={this.state.text}
            loadingText="Processing changes..."
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
}
```

**Search.css**

```
@media all and (min-width: 480px) {
  .TableQuery {
    padding: 5px 0;
  }

  .TableQuery form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 300px;
  }
}
```

As a result, the development server shows the Button as 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPodN.png) when isLoading equals true.

Yet the size of the loading portion of the Button should simply be relative to the size of the non-loading Button like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyBJr.png).

Is there any way I can lower the top portion of the Button when it is loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was due to multiple css classNames called "spinning".